# call plugin template /page with script ui.route angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading, mean-stack

Hey all can you help me, i want to call css and jquery file for template but one page, i have made it but it does not show its page and plugin file has been called!!

1. this function app.constant for call a plugin

{

```
app.constant('MODULE_CONFIG', [
  {
      name: 'alumnss',
      module: true,
      files: [
          'public/alumni/css/icomoon.css',
          'public/alumni/css/simple-line-icons.css',
          'public/alumni/css/magnific-popup.css',
          'public/alumni/css/owl.carousel.min.css',
          'public/alumni/css/owl.theme.default.min.css',
          // 'public/alumni/css/salvattore.css',
          'public/alumni/css/style.css',
          'public/alumni/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js',
          'public/alumni/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js',
          'public/alumni/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js',
          'public/alumni/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
          'public/alumni/js/owl.carousel.min.js',
          'public/alumni/js/jquery.countTo.js',
          'public/alumni/js/main.js'
      ]
  }
]).config(['$ocLazyLoadProvider', 'MODULE_CONFIG', function($ocLazyLoadProvider, MODULE_CONFIG) {
  $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
      debug: false,
      events: false,
      modules: MODULE_CONFIG
  });}]);}
```

2. this route a page

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, MODULE_CONFIG) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/alumnis');
$stateProvider
 .state('alumnis', {
 url: '/alumnis',
 templateUrl: 'alumni.html',
 controller:'',
 resolve: load(['alumnss']) // **THIS CALL FROM 'MODULE_CONFIG' has been called, But the html page not showing **
 })

function load(srcs, callback) {
        return {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$q',
              function( $ocLazyLoad, $q ){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var promise  = false;
                srcs = angular.isArray(srcs) ? srcs : srcs.split(/\s+/);
                if(!promise){
                  promise = deferred.promise;
                }
                angular.forEach(srcs, function(src) {
                  promise = promise.then( function(){
                    angular.forEach(MODULE_CONFIG, function(module) {
                      if( module.name == src){
                        if(!module.module){
                          name = module.files;
                        }else{
                          name = module.name;
                        }
                      }else{
                        name = src;
                      }
                    });
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load(name);
                  } );
                });
                deferred.resolve();
                return callback ? promise.then(function(){ return callback(); }) : promise;
            }]
        }
      }
      });
```

and [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaCMf.png), for page blank not show the template, or something wrong with the code???    help me please???

Comment: This is not complete example, can you write a plunker or fiddle for this.

Comment: ok wait i try, thanx for comment

Comment: I have a git example which is https://github.com/mdshohelrana/AngularJSArchitecture you can try to test your code into this architecture. every things is same to you.

Comment: @Shohel thanks for example, but i use ocLazyLoad with ui-router, can you help me this my plunker https://embed.plnkr.co/uuVhGdya3UtyLUwIU1Y5/
i want load plugin css in app2.js for the example.

Comment: are you familiar with debug. find the problem to load method. ok no problem i will fix this example.

Comment: Wow ok, thanks for the help

Comment: sorry brother, $ocLazyLoad does not work properly right now, i could not understand. what is the problem. I think your ocLazyLoad.core.js js has some problem. you can try other. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten your solution

Change the ocLazyLoad CDN like this

```
<script data-require="oclazyload@1.0.9" data-semver="1.0.9" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/oclazyload/1.1.0/ocLazyLoad.min.js"></script>
```

and write the code for JQ_CONFIG not MODULE_CONFIG

```
var app = angular.module('routerApp');

app.constant('JQ_CONFIG', {
    callplugincss: [
       'style.css'
    ]
});

app.constant('MODULE_CONFIG', [{
    name: 'ngGrid',
    module: true,
    files: [
        'js of ng grid'
    ]
}]);
```

and change in dependency

```
routerApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, MODULE_CONFIG, JQ_CONFIG) {
```

I think it will work. thanks.